# Relation between convexity, continuity and finiteness

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty]$ be increasing with $\varphi(0)=\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\varphi(t)=0$ and $\lim_{t\to \infty}\varphi(t)=\infty$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$: As a convex function,  $\varphi$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$ if and only if $\varphi$ is finite on $[0,\infty)$.

The function $\varphi(t)= \begin{cases} 
      0, & 0\leq t\le 1/2 \\
      \frac{2t-1}{1-t}, & 1/2< t< 1 \\
      \infty, & t\geq 1 
   \end{cases}
$ is convex and continuous but not finite on $[0,\infty)$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: That functions isn't continuous on $[0,\infty)$, only a subset. If a function takes the value $\infty$ then it cannot be continuous at that point.

Comment: @TSF i write the function explictly. The continuity in $[0,\infty]$ means that $\lim_{s\to t}f(s)=f(t)$ for every point $t\in(0,\infty)$ regardless of whether $f(t)$ is finite or infinite.

Comment: Ah I see your point. Perhaps then the issue is with the fact that $\phi$ must be increasing. Now, some authors say increasing to mean nondecreasing and then use strictly increasing to mean increasing. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @TSF $\varphi$ is increasing mean nondecreasing in here.

Comment: Then you have found a counter example. Certainly that function is convex and continuous but it is not finite. I think the authors must mean that "continuous in $[0,\infty)$" means continuous with respect to the usual topology, not the extended real line.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but its too long.

I think this is hard to evaluate without knowing the exact definitions that are being used for convexity and continuity: In my experience these are much more commonly discussed for functions taking finite values. It seems there are reasonable definitions of continuity and convexity for which you are correct. However, I think you lose some important aspects of convexity when you do this.

One can define a topology on $[0,\infty]$ by taking a basic of opens set of the form $(a,b)$ and $(b,\infty]$ where $0<a<b<\infty$. In this topology your function is continuous. You can then take the usual definition of convex function: $f$ is convex if $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$. With this set up you are correct.

However, another typical definition of convexity for functions is that the epigraph of the function is convex. The epigraph of $f$ denote $epi(f)$ is the set
$$
epi(f)=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq f(x)\}.
$$
Now the problem is, in our topology $epi(f)$ is a compact convex set. However, $epi(f)$ is NOT the convex hull of its extreme points.

You also lose existence of unique optimizers for many functions on compact sets in this topology. For example, the linear functional $y$ achieves a maximum on $epi(f)$ at every point with an infinite $y$ coordinate.

The point is, you should expect to lose things when going to the extend real numbers and you likely cannot get a totally satisfying notion of convexity here. Uniqueness optimizers and spanning properties of extreme points are some of the most interesting things about convex sets, so you have payed a big price here.